# Autoscroll to the textView cursor which is placed inside the UITableViewCell is not working in iOS11

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I have an autoscroll functionality of the tableView based on the `UITextView` cursor location inside the `cell` when editing.

It worked in the previous iOS versions. Starting from iOS11 it is broken.

I have set the `tableView` `contentInset` based on the keyboard height. For autoscrolling am using following code in `textViewDidChange`

```
if let confirmedTextViewCursorPosition = textView.selectedTextRange?.end {

            let caretPosition = textView.caretRect(for: confirmedTextViewCursorPosition)
            var textViewActualPosition = tableView.convert(caretPosition, from: textView.superview?.superview)
            textViewActualPosition.origin.y += 22.0 
            tableView.scrollRectToVisible(textViewActualPosition, animated: false)

        }
```

Comment: Could you please add a bit more code on this? e.g. the code for the `UITableView` and `UITableViewCell`

Answer (score 0):

[Askh1t](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2372189/aksh1t) is correct, here is my implementation:

```
    var info = notification.userInfo!
    var keyboardSize:CGRect = (info[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as! NSValue).cgRectValue
    if keyboardSize.size.height <= 0 { // to fix bug on iOS 11
        keyboardSize = (info[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as! NSValue).cgRectValue
    }
```

as well as the full modular implementation that should work for you:

```
//MARK: - Properties
var activeTextView: UITextView?

//MARK: - Scroll View Notifications
// add in viewDidLoad
func registerForKeyboardNotifications(){
    //Adding notifies on keyboard appearing
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: Notification.Name.UIKeyboardWillShow, object: nil, queue: nil, using: keyboardWasShown)
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: Notification.Name.UIKeyboardWillHide, object: nil, queue: nil, using: keyboardWillBeHidden)
}

//add in viewWillDisappear
func deregisterFromKeyboardNotifications(){
    //Removing notifies on keyboard appearing
    NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self, name: Notification.Name.UIKeyboardDidShow, object: nil)
    NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self, name: Notification.Name.UIKeyboardWillHide, object: nil)
}

func keyboardWasShown(notification: Notification) -> Void {
    //Need to calculate keyboard exact size due to Apple suggestions
    self.tableView.isScrollEnabled = true
    var info = notification.userInfo!
    var keyboardSize:CGRect = (info[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as! NSValue).cgRectValue
    if keyboardSize.size.height <= 0 { // to fix bug on iOS 11
        keyboardSize = (info[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as! NSValue).cgRectValue
    }
    self.tableView.contentInset.bottom = keyboardSize.height //add this much
    self.tableView.scrollIndicatorInsets.bottom = keyboardSize.height //scroll too it.

    var aRect : CGRect = self.view.frame
    aRect.size.height -= keyboardSize.height
    if let activeField = self.activeTextView {
        if (!aRect.contains(activeField.frame.origin)){
            self.tableView.scrollRectToVisible(activeField.frame, animated: true)
        }
    }
}

func keyboardWillBeHidden(notification: Notification){
    self.tableView.contentInset.bottom = 0
    self.tableView.isScrollEnabled = true
    self.tableView.alwaysBounceVertical = true
}

func textViewDidBeginEditing(_ textView: UITextView){
    activeTextView = textView

}


func textViewDidEndEditing(_ textView: UITextView){
    tableView.isScrollEnabled = true
    activeTextView = nil
}
```

Comment: problem here is calculation is correct but the tableview scrolltorect is not working . when i add timer block to execute tableview.scrolltoRect its working perfectly fine

Comment: Make sure you calling your code after .isScrollEnabled is set. Synchronous blocks that update the ui need to be called on the main thread.

Comment: am just calling scrolltorect inside the main thread only but it not working for iOS 11